# Firebase and React hosting - not loading App.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use firebase to host my React App, but for some reason it is not rendering my app.js file.

I initially ran `firebase init hosting`, which ended up overwriting my index.html file.

I then ran `firebase deploy --only hosting` which published to my hosting URL.

However the content available at the hosting URL only contains info from my index.html file, and not from App.js. (Note that my public folder contains index.html, but App.js is not in the public folder).

The result is that when I run `npm run start`, the local web server shows all the content from App.js, but when I deploy, I see only the content from index.html. Below is my code, and suggestions would be appreciated:

Firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Public/Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Michael McKinney</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-performance.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import App from './components/App';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
firebase.initializeApp = {
    apiKey: "Fake",
    authDomain: "michaelmckinney-Fake.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "michaelmckinney-Fake",
    storageBucket: "michaelmckinney-Fake.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "fake",
    appId: "Fake:web:Fake",
    measurementId: "Fake"
  };

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Components/App.js:

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from "firebase";
import './App.css';
t

class App extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='text-monospace'>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
          <a
            className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
        <img src={dbank} className="App-logo" alt="logo" height="32"/>
          <b>dBank</b>
        </a>
        </nav>
        <div className="container-fluid mt-5 text-center">
        <br></br>
          <h1>{"Welcome from App.js"}</h1>
          <br></br>
          <div className="row">
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 d-flex text-center">
              <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
              <Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
                {/*add Tab deposit*/}
                {/*add Tab withdraw*/}
              </Tabs>
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: before i can even answer this question or look into it, i would suggest you remove your api keys, apiIds etc from the code you pasted above in index.js ;)

Comment: Whoops done lol

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was that I was not building correctly. After changing firebase.json to

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and running `npm build`, I deployed as expected.